# Create daily planner

Tags: tables, tabularx

I'm very new to latex, so please forgive me if my question is too general.

I want to create a daily time-blocking planner that looks something like this.
[image: schedule template]

[image: Tasks template]

Here's what I've got so far.
There's a lot of questions, like how to make every second `\hline` gray or how to make table to take full width of the page independent of the page size.

```latex
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper, portrait, margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\grayline}{\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}\cline{3-5}\arrayrulecolor{white}}
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{black}
\color{white}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{10pt}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c|X|X|X|X|}
    \cline{1-5}
    \multicolumn{5} {r|} {Date: 2021|\hspace{0.5cm}|\hspace{0.5cm}|}\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \grayline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \grayline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \grayline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \grayline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \grayline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \grayline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \grayline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \grayline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \grayline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \grayline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \grayline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \grayline
    \hspace{0.5cm} & & & & \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following may serve as a place to start from:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\grayline}{\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}\cline{1-5}\arrayrulecolor{black}}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|c|X|X|X|c}
    \cline{1-5}
    \multicolumn{5} {|l|} {Date: } \\
    \hline
    & & & && \multirow{2}{*}{1}\\ 
    \grayline
    & :30 & & &&\\ \hline
    & & & && \multirow{2}{*}{2}\\ 
    \grayline
    & :30 & & &&\\ \hline
\end{tabularx}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I've modified your solution to satisfy my needs, thank you. I have another question - how would I create one a4 paper with both the content of this two a5 pages side by side?